# Node js - Moving a file from /tmp in Amazon Lambda to an s3bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a simple screenshot program in amazon lambda which will take a screengrab of a given url in the following JSON format:

```
{
  "site": "www.google.com",
  "width": "320",
  "height": "480"
}
```

The code for my lambda function is as below:

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var webshot = require('webshot');
var request = require('request');

var s3bucket = '<bucket-name>';
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log( "Attempting to screenshot:", event.site);

  var parts = event.site.split('?'),
      base64Key = new Buffer(parts[0].toLowerCase()).toString('base64').replace(/\//g, '|').replace(/\+/g, '$') + '.png',
      options = {
        shotSize: {
          width: event.width,
          height: event.height
        }
      },
      s3 = new AWS.S3(),
      renderStream = webshot(event.site, options),
      file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + base64Key, {encoding: 'binary'}),
      bin = '';

  renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
    // bin += data.toString('binary');
    file.write(data.toString('binary'), 'binary');
  });

  renderStream.on('end', function() {
    // var options = {
    //    Bucket: s3bucket,
    //    Key: base64Key,
    //    ACL: 'public-read',
    //    body: file
    // };
    // s3.putObject(options, function(err, data) {
    //     if(err) {
    //       callback(err);
    //     } else {
    //       callback(null, 'Image uploaded to Amazon s3 bucket: ' + s3bucket);
    //     }
    // });


    var buffer = new Buffer(bin);
    s3.putObject({
        Bucket: s3bucket,
        Key: base64Key,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Body: buffer.toString('binary')
    }, function(err, data) {
       if(err) {
         callback(err);
       } else {
         callback(null, 'Image uploaded to Amazon s3 bucket: ' + s3bucket);
       }
    });
  });
}
```

**My problem is this:**

When I write the file to the /tmp directory it is there as expected, however, when I then try and upload the image from the /tmp directory to my s3 bucket it is not working correctly.

I have tried to upload the raw data (bin), and also within a buffer as commented out above. I have also tried to upload the file stream directly, though these attempts did not work.

When running on amazon the log files are not showing any errors. I have looked through the [Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) on putObject though I cannot seem to see where I am going wrong.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The problem appears to be that the file is created in /tmp but no data is written to it so when it is copied over to S3 there is a .png file with size 0 bytes

Comment: did u check, the file created correctly on /tmp directory

Comment: The problem appears to be writing to the /tmp file afterall. The file is created but is empty. Why would this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var webshot = require('webshot');
var request = require('request');
var s3bucket = '<bucket-name>';

console.log( "Attempting to screenshot:", event.site);

  var parts = event.site.split('?'),
      base64Key = new Buffer(parts[0].toLowerCase()).toString('base64').replace(/\//g, '|').replace(/\+/g, '$') + '.png',
      options = {
        shotSize: {
          width: event.width,
          height: event.height
        }
      },
      s3 = new AWS.S3(),
      renderStream = webshot(event.site, options),
      file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + base64Key, {encoding: 'binary'}),
      bin = '';

  renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
    // bin += data.toString('binary');
    file.write(data.toString('binary'), 'binary');
  });

  renderStream.on('end', function() {

        fs.readFile(path, function (err, file_buffer) {

            var params = {
                Bucket: s3bucket,
                Key: 'base64Key',
                Body: file_buffer
            };

            s3.putObject(params, function (err, pres) {
                if (err) {
                   callback(err);
                } else {
                      callback(null, 'Image uploaded to Amazon s3 bucket: ' + s3bucket);
                }
            });
        });
  });
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is the problems here ?